# Can someone explain this react native code snippet to me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, destructuring

I'm starting to look into react native, and for most of if, im doing good.
But, although I know the concept of destructuring, I'm, scratching my head with this snippet of code.

```
var {
          View,
          Text,
          Image,
          Animated,
          StatusBarIOS,
          TouchableOpacity,
          DeviceEventEmitter
    } = React;
```

Can someone explain this to me?
Thanks!

Comment: Very unclear what information you are looking for as you've already mentioned that you understand [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clearness. Was goign to clarify and saw the above answer witch was exactly what i was wondering. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just ES6 object destructuring. It is essentially creating a new variable for each one of the keywords listed in the object.

It is equivilant to :

```
var View = React.View;
var Text = React.Text;
var Image = React.Image;
var Animated = React.Animated;
```

.. etc

If this is unclear at all look at a simple object as an example:

```
const person = {
  name: 'sam',
  gender: 'male',
  age: 52
}

// create a variable for any property you want from the person object
let { name, age } = person;

console.log(name) // 'sam'
console.log(age) // 52..
```

As mentioned in the comments below because you are already using ES6 syntax you are most likely using a build tool or in an environment that supports ES6 and you should opt to use `let` or `const` instead of the ES5 `var`

Comment: OP clearly specified that they know about it already. Not really sure so what they are asking about...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Clearly the OP does _not_ understand destructuring. This answer provides more information that will help the OP understand. +1. I should add that, as long as we're making use of ES6 destructuring, you might as well throw out `var` and use `let` or `const` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is ES2015 "[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)". In simple words, this is a shorthand for assigning multiple variables in a single statement, extracting their values from the object at the right of the `=` operator. Is the same as doing:

```
var View = React.View,
    Text = React.Text,
    Image = React.Image,
//... and so on.
```

So, the important part to note here is that this is a short way of the following:

```
var {
  View: View,
  Text: Text, 
  // ...   
} = React;
```

But since, the newly created variables **have the same name** as React object's properties, it can be simplified to:

```
var {
  View,
  Text, 
  // ...   
} = React;
```